# Why "version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found" always shown but it's actually exist?

Tags: c++, gcc, runtime-error

In my lab's cluster machine, I have 2 compiler, one is the gcc4 and one is the gcc5. The gcc4 libraries are in the standard directory (i.e. /usr/lib64), while the gcc5 libraries are in the /usr/local/lib64.

So I was compiling my program and check the library with the ldd:

```
ldd bin/cell

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffad1fc000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00000039f0c00000)
libsundials_cvode.so.2 => /opt/Lib/sundials-2.7.0/lib/libsundials_cvode.so.2 (0x00002b16bab69000)
libsundials_nvecserial.so.2 => /opt/Lib/sundials-2.7.0/lib/libsundials_nvecserial.so.2 (0x00002b16bad93000)
libsundials_nvecparallel.so.2 => /opt/Lib/sundials-2.7.0/lib/libsundials_nvecparallel.so.2 (0x00002b16baf98000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00000039efc00000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00000037c7600000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b16bb1cd000)
libmpi.so.20 => /opt/Lib/openmpi-2.1.3/lib/libmpi.so.20 (0x00002b16bb570000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000039f0000000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b16bb863000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000039f0400000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000039ef800000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00000039f0800000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00000039f1000000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000039ef000000)
libopen-rte.so.20 => /opt/Lib/openmpi-2.1.3/lib/libopen-rte.so.20 (0x00002b16bba7c000)
libopen-pal.so.20 => /opt/Lib/openmpi-2.1.3/lib/libopen-pal.so.20 (0x00002b16bbd05000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00000039f3c00000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00000039fca00000)
```

As you can see that the libstdc++ is in /usr/local/lib64 in this binary.

However, when I try to submit the job using the qsub command, it gives me the error message:

```
/scratch4/maincode/elecphy/cellc/bin/cell: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /scratch4/maincode/elecphy/cellc/bin/cell)
```

Instead of checking the /usr/local/lib64, it checked my /usr/lib64, that is the old GCC4 libs directory.

My questions are:
How can this be happened?
Is there any workaround to force the binary to direct to the correct GCC libs directory?

Comment: differences in environment variables? Try explicitly setting "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"?

Comment: what do you mean explicitly? Can I give LD_LIBRARY_PATH as additional arguments?